# Random freezes and shut down problems on hp laptop

Tags: shutdown, hp, crash

I have had an HP laptop for quite a few years. More concretely the HP Pavilion dv7-6c07ss model.

This laptop has two graphic cards, and intel one and a Radeon one. My radeon card started malfunctioning and I couldn't use windows 7 anymore, and had to switch to 10 which had the option of disconnecting one of the cards. The latest updates however usually remove this feature, or just do something to it, and I have to revert to previous versions. Even if have updates blocked they sometimes bite me in the ass anyway.

I got tired of this and decided to test Ubuntu on a 200 gb partition. I have been using it for a few weeks, and when it works fine, it's very nice. However, it randomly freezes when I install or uninstall apps from the gnome apps manager (don't know the actual name), and sometimes it is also unable to shutdown for some reason (at first I thought it was due to the google drive clients I installed (insync and then odrive), but I removed them and it still does it (less often though)). Other times it just freezes on startup (a few seconds after the desktop appears on screen). I don't know if this is related to the graphics card problem. More often than not I am able to go hours working, no problem.

My version is Ubuntu 18.04 lts (the latest I found on the website), and my knowledge of the OS is next to zero, as I am completely new to it.

The apps I have installed at the moment are the ones that come with the system, chrome, kdnlive, VLC, and gimp (these last two have never been used, I just opened them after installing to see if they worked).

The first time it froze however was seconds after the first time I booted it (bad omen), so maybe these apps are not related at all.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: When asking for the extensions this is what I get

```
jsampe@jsampe-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC:~$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 jsampe jsampe 4096 mar 15 22:16 .
drwx------ 3 jsampe jsampe 4096 mar 16 21:26 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 jsampe jsampe 4096 mar 15 22:11 add-on-desktop@maestroschan.fr
jsampe@jsampe-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC:~$ ^C
jsampe@jsampe-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC:~$
```

The version is Ubuntu 18.04.02 LTS Bionic Beaver

I don't know how to check for the drivers that are in use. I tried to look for propietary drivers on the HP website but they only offer windows drivers

Edit 2: This is what I get with the command `free -h`

```
jsampe@jsampe-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC:~$ free -h
              total usado libre compartido búfer/caché disponible
Memoria:        7,7G        804M        5,9G        228M        1,1G        6,5G
Swap:          2,0G          0B        2,0G
jsampe@jsampe-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC:~$ ^C
```

I have Ubuntu in Spanish, sorry about that

In software and updates, under the additional controllers tab, it says that I don't have any additional controllers.

As for the Radeon drivers, I searched the internet and found out the command `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`. This is what I get:

```
jsampe@jsampe-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [103c:185d]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Radeon HD 7470M [103c:185d]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
jsampe@jsampe-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC:~$
```

These are the results of the memtest in one pass

https://photos.app.goo.gl/UUSsF37rYhyLF6gTA

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91244/discussion-on-question-by-jsampe-random-freezes-and-shut-down-problems-on-hp-lap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

To disable the AMD Radeon video card, try this...

In `terminal`...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/modprobe.d/radeon.conf` # create a file

Enter this into the file:

```
blacklist radeon
```

Save the file and quit gedit.

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Comment: This is what I get after inputting that command: 
** (gedit:3078): WARNING **: 11:11:59.707: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported

** (gedit:3078): WARNING **: 11:11:59.708: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported

** (gedit:3078): WARNING **: 11:12:01.010: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported

Comment: The file is created though, and if I enter the command again the changes are saved

Comment: @jsampe  Yes, they're just warnings, but it's a gedit bug. However, after reboot, is the Radeon disabled, and have your symptoms gone away?

Comment: I've been using Linux with no problem all this week, so I am assuming the problems have finally disappeared. Thanks for your time and dedication!!